# memory leak in iPhone Obj C code

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I'm parsing an XML string and have a memory leak.  I know this code is leaking, but not sure what the fix is:

http://pastie.org/580694

Code like this appears to be fundamentally flawed:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)value{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"problem_id"]){
        currentProblem.problemId = [[value copy] intValue];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"rule_instance_id"]){
        currentProblem.ruleInstanceId = [value copy];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]){
        currentProblem.desc = [value copy];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"name"]){
        currentProblem.name = [value copy];
```

but not sure how I should deal with grabbing the found characters and retaining/releasing them.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of the `Problem` class, let the compiler deal with property memory management for you:

- Define string properties with `@property (retain) NSString *desc;`. This will make sure your class increments the reference count on string values it stores (and decrement it if another value is stored later on).
- Define int properties with `@property (assign) int problemId`. Ints don't need to be copied of ref-counted.

In the `dealloc:` method, make sure to release all the retained properties, e.g. `[desc release]`.

Finally, you do not need to copy `value` before assigning to `currentProblem`'s properties. `currentProblem.desc = value` will do the right thing. If you leave `[value copy]` in place, that would keep on leaking.

As for the code in the question, it leaks in a couple of places:

- `[[value copy] intValue]` leaks each time `parser:foundCharacters:` is called, as the copy is never released.
- The string members of `currentProblem` leak when `currentProblem` is released, as the current implementation of `dealloc:` does not release them.

Comment: I'd use `copy` instead of `retain` on the string if I were you - there are mutable `NSString` subclasses.

Comment: Ah good point. The rest of the solution should hold. If the strings don't need to be mutable, an NSString + retain would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`currentProblem.problemId = ...` is equivalent to `[currentProblem setProblemId:...]`. You have almost certainly declared problemId to have a retain or copy setter, so `setProblemId:` retains the object passed. This is normal and good.

```
currentProblem.desc = [value copy];
```

`-copy` is one of the [three magic words](http://robnapier.net/blog/three-magic-words-6), which means the returned value is retained, and then you retain it again in the setter. So you are double-retaining; memory leak.

`value` is an NSString, so is immutable. There is no reason to make a copy of it. Many pointers may share an immutable object safely. This code should be:

```
currentProblem.desc = value;
```

This line is a little different:

```
currentProblem.problemId = [[value copy] intValue];
```

In this case, problemId is clearly an assign property (or you would quickly crash), but you're still calling `-copy` on `value`, causing its retain count to go up by one, thus leaking it. This code should be:

```
currentProblem.problemId = [value intValue];
```

In short, stop copying the objects here and your memory leak will go away. Copying is somewhat rare in ObjC.

Comment: +1 Spot on, just remove the copy commands and memory leak gone.  The fact you've used the copy command here shows you still need to "get" OO a little more...